# Python, Flask, and jinja templates - How to iterate over a dictionary created server side

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am using flask.

On the server server when a page loads I create a dictionary.

```
@app.route('/edit_creative', methods=["GET", "POST"])
@login_required
def edit_creative():
    if request.method == "POST": 
        pass

    query = """select * from mystable"""
    print query
    rows = execute_query(query,select=True)
    creative_handler={}
    for row in rows:
        j = row[2].strip("'")
        j = json.loads(j)
        creative_handler[row[1]]=j

    return render_template("edit_creatives.html",title = 'Edit Creative')
```

On the client side I want to iterate over the hash:

```
{% for crid, object in creative_handler.iteritems() %}

{{ crid }}<br>

{% endfor %}
```

On the page I get this error

```
UndefinedError: 'creative_handler' is undefined
```

So..how do I use jinja templates to iterate over a hash creates server side?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to pass `creative_handler` to the template:

```
return render_template("edit_creatives.html", title='Edit Creative', creative_handler=creative_handler)
```

Answer (score 3):

Well you need to pass in the variable(s) you want to use, in the template.

```
>>> from flask import render_template
>>> help(render_template)
render_template(template_name, **context)
    Renders a template from the template folder with the given
    context.

    :param template_name: the name of the template to be rendered
    :param context: the variables that should be available in the
                    context of the template.
```

so `return render_template("edit_creatives.html",title = 'Edit Creative', creative_handler = creative_handler)`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
return render_template("edit_creatives.html",title = 'Edit Creative', creative_handler = creative_handler)
```

If creative_handler contains your data anyway.

You have to actually pass the object to the template so it can be seen and give it a name which you then use in the template. Also FYI the code is not executed client side, it's built inside your app then sent to the client. They just see the HTML that results from the loop etc.